# How to store product quantity in database

Tags: mysql, database

I have database with three tables

```
product         (productID,productName,productDescription) 
size            (sizeID , sizeName) eg. s ,m ,l ,8,10,12,37,35..etc 
ProductDetails  (ProductDetailsID, productID(FK) , sizeID (FK))
```

I want to store the quantity of each product and it size for example there are 5 in stock for product 1 of size s, 10 in stock for product 4 size 37 ..etc

In which table should I place the quantity ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just calculate this at runtime.  Are you anticipating several million rows?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "calculate this at runtime"? could you explain this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store it in ProductDetails only as the quantity is dependent upon the product and its size both.

Comment: I tired to store the quantity on ProductDetails but it allow me to store the same Product with the same size twice with different quantity and I don't want that to happen for example `product 1 size 10 quantity 30` &  `product 1 size 10 quantity 45` will be stored twice but with different ProductDetails ID

Comment: You can put primary key on a combination of all productId,size,quantity

Comment: Create table ProductDetails(Product ID F.K.,......, primary key(product_id,size_id,quantity). Something of this kind will help you

Comment: oh I see thank you I will check Primary key combination

Comment: Awesome. Please upvote/accept the answer if it helps you. <Click on the tick to accept>

Answer (score 0):

You should use another table.
It could be called ProductSizeQuantity(id, ProductId, sizeID, Quantity)

Comment: Why not in ProductDetails itself? Why to make another table for the same?

Comment: I'm just assuming here, but if a product have a size, then ProductDetails have information about the product, not the product with the size, that would be ModelDetail.

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
product (productID,productName,productDescription) 
size (sizeID , sizeName) 
ProductDetails (ProductDetailsID, productID(FK) , sizeID (FK))
```

in my opinion you need:

```
product (productID[PK], productName, productDescription) 
size (size[PK]) 
ProductDetails (productID[PK] , size[PK], quantity)
```

notes:

for size it is not required sizeid + sizeName, but only one column with size name

quantity is in product details table, in this table id your PK is productId+Size you'll have one tuple for each for each size of the product

Comment: Many database designers promote having an auto-increment ID column as the primary key in every table. I see you don't subscribe to this (neither do I), but I don't think it's necessary to remove that from his design as part of your answer.

Comment: Just show where to add the quantity based on his original design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Product table : 
id 
name 
description

Size table : 
id 
product_id 
 
size

Quantity table : 
id 
size_id 
stock

Fetch product first, fetch sizes based on product and fetch its Quantity based on size id.